# SQLiteOpenHelper updating a table in a Database

Tags: android

I have a class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper. The two functions overloaded are

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase dataBase, int oldVersion,
            int newVersion) {

    }
```

In the OnCreate function i add SQL scripts to create a table. Now what if i want to upgrade a table in the Database.

When is the onUpgrade function called ?

What are the oldVersion and newVersion int values ?

Do these allow me to create a versioning on my db ?

Like in version 2 i want to add a new table and in version 3 i want to add a new column to an existing database table ?

How can i do this ?

The onCreate function will be called each time i create an object of the class, or will Android call this only when the application is installed ?

Answer (score 1):

> What are the `oldVersion` and `newVersion` int values?

These are used to version your database. The database version is passed in the constructor of your SQLiteOpenHelper.

> When is the `onUpgrade` function called?

`onUpgrade` is called when you `newVersion` > `oldVersion`

> Do these allow me to create a versioning on my db?

Yes these values allow you to version your database.

> Like in version 2 i want to add a new table and in version 3 i want to
>   add a new column to an existing database table?

In the `onUpgrade` method execute a `CREATE TABLE` query that will create a new table in your database. Likewise if you want to add a new column use the `ALTER TABLE` statement.

> The onCreate function will be called each time i create an object of
>   the class, or will Android call this only when the application is
>   installed?

`OnCreate` is called if your application hasn't created a database yet, in situations like - you are launching your app for the first time, running the app for the first time after clearing its data.

Comment: So the version passed in the constructor is the newVersion, and after the onUpdate version is called, this becomes the oldVersion ? @Ragunath Jawahar.

Comment: To be precise, it becomes the current version. In the next update if you increment your DB_VERSION, then it becomes the oldVersion.

Answer (score 0):

I give you a snipped, here i set database version to 1. And if i need to upgrade all database, i'll make it 2 or something else and SQLiteOpenHelper will know that this is a new version of database, and call onUpgrade method...

```
private final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private final String DATABASE_NAME = "yourDatabase";

private class DBOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DBOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(ctx, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_SIGNIN_FIRST);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
         // you can drop table and re create it here.
    }

}
```

Comment: so wher does the oldVersion and newVersion come into play ?